# Generated file for data class inheriting base entity does not contain parent's property

Tags: kotlin, objectbox

I am currently using ObjectBox version 2.3.1 with Kotlin and trying to write a data class entity which inherits base entity class, but generated object_.java file for data class does not contain property of its parent. With the given code below, `ChildEntity_.uploaded` or `ChildEntity_.dateAdded` are not available.
How would I make `ChildEntity_` class to contain `ParentEntity` properties?

#### Code

```
@BaseEntity
abstract class ParentEntity<B : Enum<B>>(
    var uploaded: Boolean = false,

    var dateAdded: Date = Date(),

    @Index
    @Convert(converter = UuidConverter::class, dbType = String::class)
    val actionUuid: UUID = UUID.randomUUID()
) {

  abstract fun getAction(): B?
}
```

```
@Entity
data class ChildEntity(
    var id: Long = 0,

    @Convert(converter = FavouriteStoreActionConverter::class, dbType = String::class)
    var childAction: Action.MyAction? = null
) : ParentEntity<Action.MyAction>() {

  constructor(id: Long, favourite: Boolean) : this(
      storeId = storeId,
      childAction = if (favourite) Action.MyAction.FAVOURITE
      else Action.MyAction.UNFAVOURITE
  )

  override fun getAction(): Action.MyAction? {
    return childAction
  }
}
```

Comment: Your post doesn't contain a question. Please state your question clearly. For example: "How can I modify the code to make `ChildEntity_.uploaded` and `ChildEntity_.dateAdded` accessible from _____?

Comment: @Nikolas Thank you for the comment. I edited to make the question more clear.

Comment: Can you let me know if using a regular class instead of a `data class` for `ChildEntity` works?

Comment: @Uwe I tried with regular class as well, but it didn't work either.

Comment: Alright, turns out this is due to the base entity being generic. Until this is fixed (if it can be) you will have to get rid of the generics: `@BaseEntity abstract class ParentEntity(`

Comment: Update: this should be fixed with the next update.

Comment: @Uwe Thank you for the update!!